# Virtualbox not able to run VMs. Kernel driver not installed

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, kubuntu, virtualization, konsole

VirtualBox does not want to run VMs. It says the kernel driver is not installed. I reinstalled the virtualbox-dkms package and ran 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root but it still doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The simplest solution is to disable Secure Boot in system BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI (aka BIOS) settings as it is mentioned in the error message.